# How do purposefully protect a filename from being changed from anything including timestamps when uploading and downloading from a website?

Tags: php, file, server

I want to protect a filename from being altered or changed when uploading and then downloading from a website. For example if i upload a `this.ppt` file it gets changed to `this_1.ppt` file when downloaded or a `music.mp4` to `music_1.mp4`. how do i prevent any website from making that change?

What if the website has a timestamp? For, example a filename is `this.ppt` and the website when downloading changes it to `this_30-11-2015.ppt`.

Is there like a filelocker out there or any program that can do that for any file and prevent any site from altering the filename?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do this? Because it's almost certainly impossible, but it's likely if you're using this to solve another problem a simpler solution exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

If you are uploading a file to a site that you do not own, then there is nothing you can do... The owner of the site will choose whatever name he/she wants for files that you upload.

If you are downloading a file from a site that you own, then the only thing you can do is "suggest" a file name that the browser will display to the user by default. But the user will always be able to change/rename it to whatever he/she wants.